# Extrude Geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, computational-geometry

I'm currently loading an STL onject into my three.js scene.

For some reason, it takes a lot of GPU resources to render/animate, slowing the entire scene down so I've been considering alternatives.

As it's quite a simple shape, I thought I could use create the 2D shape and extrude it.

The 3D shape is a square frame (*it's a photo frame*), no curves or any other clever geometry.

Initially, I thought about creating 4x 3D oblongs, rotating each one by 90 degrees and placing them just right in the scene to make it look like a frame - but that's not ideal.

[image: Here's a 2D shape (it's perfectly square):]

[image: And here's a preview of the STL model]

So as an alternative to loading the STL model into the scene, how can I create this shape in three.js (*with empty space in the centre*) and then extrude it to give it some depth?

Comment: try exporting your model in a different format like obj, fbx, and optimising the mesh in a 3d modeling program.

Comment: You just have to create a shape with a hole and extrude it, and add a box below

Comment: Could you post your code? There's no reason that a scene with ~40 vertices would slow down your GPU, I'm thinking you're probably re-building the geometry once per frame, or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic extrusion example: [`Shape`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Shape) -> [`ExtrudeGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) -> `Mesh`

```js
const { renderer, scene, camera } = initThree();


//Create a frame shape..
var frame = new THREE.Shape();
frame.moveTo(-4, -3);
frame.lineTo( 4, -3);
frame.lineTo( 4,  3);
frame.lineTo(-4,  3);

//..with a hole:
var hole = new THREE.Path();
hole.moveTo(-3, -2);
hole.lineTo( 3, -2);
hole.lineTo( 3,  2);
hole.lineTo(-3,  2);
frame.holes.push(hole);

//Extrude the shape into a geometry, and create a mesh from it:
var extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 1,
    depth: 1,
    bevelEnabled: false,
};
var geom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(frame, extrudeSettings);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffaaaa }));


scene.add(mesh);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Sphinxxxx/298702f070e34a5df30326cd9943260a/raw/16afc701da1ed8ed267a896907692d8acdce9b7d/init-three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for - looks easy enough when you know how!!

Comment: using this method results into a solid with "double faces", i.e. each face is made of two overlapped triangles; this prevents me from successfully exporting it into a 3d-printable STL: I get the STL, but I have to manually delete all double faces; is there a method to prevent "triangling" of the faces using THREE.ExtrudeGeometry() ?